# How can I decrease FULLTEXT initialization time?

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I'm trying to decrease execution time of the a query. Using `SHOW PROFILE`, `FULLTEXT initialization` takes about 0.3, which is too high. Other values are at normal level.

How can I decrease **FULLTEXT initialization** time? Any suggestions?

*Once I figured out FULLTEXT initialization is the problem i created this question. Please see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72188/mysql-fulltext-selection-performance for more information*